# dynamic objects replace the propertie instead of adding to it

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So, I am trying to make a daily planner, and you need to fill in tasks for specific days. The tasks are stored in a state object. Each task is placed inside their own dynamic properties, based on the the year, month, day, type of task, subject and name of task.
Here is what I am currently doing to sort it

```
export const addTask = (tasks, fields) => {
// tasks are directly from the state
// fields are gathered from a form, then put as an argument for this function

  console.log("pre add", tasks);
  fields.subject = capitalizeFirstLetter(fields.subject);
  fields.name = capitalizeFirstLetter(fields.name);

  tasks[fields.date[0]] = {};
  tasks[fields.date[0]][fields.date[1]] = {};
  tasks[fields.date[0]][fields.date[1]][fields.date[2]] = {};
  tasks[fields.date[0]][fields.date[1]][fields.date[2]][fields.type] = {};
  tasks[fields.date[0]][fields.date[1]][fields.date[2]][fields.type][fields.subject] = {};
  tasks[fields.date[0]][fields.date[1]][fields.date[2]][fields.type][fields.subject][fields.name] = {};
  tasks[fields.date[0]][fields.date[1]][fields.date[2]][fields.type][fields.subject][fields.name] = fields.details;

  console.log("post add", tasks);

  return tasks;
};
```

this is my state:

```
const state = {
  tasks: {// this is what I put in the addTask function},
  dates: {
    monthCounter: 0,
    targetDate: {},
  },
};
```

This is also how I call the function:

```
state.tasks = addTask(state.tasks, fields);
```

whenever I add another task, the last task gets deleted/replaced. Even if both tasks have the same subject, but different names, the first one will get deleted.

Comment: What is that: `tasks[fields.date[0]][fields.date[1]][fields.date[2]][fields.type][fields.subject][fields.name] = fields.details;`.  I think you need to rethink the structure you're using.

Comment: that's how I'm organizing it, this ends up being ```year:{month:{day:{type:{subject:{name:[detailsArray]}}}}}}; ``` in the console

Comment: It's bad design. Good luck with maintenance. How are you going to filter a particular type efficiently.  Also subject is probably unique so that make no sense.

Comment: If you have 2 tasks in the year, the second addTask will rest the whole year. Do `tasks[fields.date[0]] = tasks[fields.date[0]] || {}; `instead.

Comment: I'll try that, but even if it works I'm probably going to change it